# Wordpress dashboard locked out

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I just changed one word manually in one of wordpress plugin files related to shortcode. It locked me out of dashboard. I then reversed the change I made but the issue remains.

Can anybody tell me why the issue is still there when I have undone the change I made. Is there some cache issue or something else. What is the solution now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To help you out it would be beneficial to know what exactly happens when you try to access the dashboard. What message do you get?

The first thing that comes to my mind is that possibly, your WP is in maintenance mode. If so, there would be a .maintenance file in your root directory (where WordPress resides). Once you delete that file, you'll be able to access the dashboard again.

But it could be a number of issues ...

Cache: that depends if you use a caching plugin. If so, you can navigate to wp-content/cache and delete its contents.

Comment: When I try to access dashboard I get an error screen. I have mentioned the error above. Moreover my WP is not in maintenance mode

Comment: Try to enter a _ before the plugin folder eltdf-lms will most likely make your dashboard accessible again. There remains an error as the message says, it also says which line the error appears. You could just re-install the plugin or revert to the latest state - do you use Git? If not, this could help to avoid such situations.

Comment: Dashboard got accessible after adding _ before plugin folder. The plugin was shown as deactivated. I again tried to activate it but there was again an issue and dashboard lockedout

Comment: Yes, of course, if you repeat the exact same steps and create the same scenario again (faulty plugin activated), the same error will occur again. You need to fix the error that you posted above, on line 7 (presumably) ... If you did not modify the plugin, I suggest re-installing it from scratch (original version without error)...